# How to clear a default username that is saved and shown everytime I visit my rails app hosted on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm a newbie to development and I've been trying to debug something and haven't had much luck. Please bare with rookie knowledge.

I have built a small and simple rails app that I deployed on heroku where you have to sign up as a user by creating a profile, after which you can enter an address or zipcode to find the nearest gyms in your vicinity, which triggers the google places/geocoder api and brings you some results. The app works fine, but for some reason the version on heroku by default has a user that is stored or cached? when I land on my page. I did heroku pg:psql to check and I dont even see that user in my heroku database. On my local environment it works fine and no users are shown by default on the root page of my app when I run my server.

I looked at older threads on SO and I saw somebody saying to type heroku run `rake tmp:clear` but that gave me this response:

```
Running `rake tmp:cache:clear` attached to terminal... up, run.3757
stty: standard input: unable to perform all requested operations
```

Any advice/help is greatly appreciated. I only have about two weeks worth of rails knowledge! Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide screenshot and code of the page which shows this cached user?

Comment: Just fixed it, thank you for replying though, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**! I thought it was related to my code or some inconsistency that happened while I deployed! I stupidly had saved that user when I originally created him when my browser(chrome) prompted me, save password for user? I should have just chosen never or closed out of it. I just when into my settings and manage passwords and deleted the fact that I had chosen to save it. I love how answers get solved right after you ask for help.